# Simulink Stateflow: add invariants to state

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow, simulink-library

Hi I am creating a hybrid automata model using Stateflow. I was wondering if it's is possible to add invariants to a state?

Answer (score 1):

So far there is no provision to directly add invariants in stateflow